# Entity Framework: how to find transaction isolation level in SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

`BeginTransaction` method is used to manage transactions in Entity Framework 6. It allows to set isolation level for transaction as you may see in code below (just a sample):

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        context.Entities.Add(new Entity());

        context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    } 
}
```

The problem is: when I use SQL Server Profiler, I cann't find any information about isolation level for real SQL transaction.

### Attempt #1:

I tried to trace ALL kinds of events and search by "isolation" keyword in trace results. Only two events I found:

```
EventClass          TextData
-------------------------------------------------------------
ExistingConnection  set transaction isolation level read committed
AuditLogin          set transaction isolation level read committed
```

`READ COMMITTED` is always in these events. So it is not about my code, because `IsolationLevel.Serializable` is set above.

### Attempt #2:

For the transaction has been started and not committed yet, it is possible to take `SPID` and manually select real isolation level from `dm_exec_sessions` view:

```
SELECT transaction_isolation_level
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @Tran_SPID
```

This is very undesirable way.

Is it possible to record isolation level for any EF-generated transaction/session in profiler directly? Maybe I just use wrong tool?

P.S. Entity Framework 6.1.3 and MS SQL Server 2012 on board.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Currently, I'm also trying to verify if Entity Framework is actually using the isolation level that I want, but I've had no luck with it yet.

Comment: @Rudey as I remember - no, I didn't. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find a transaction isolation level in profiler as it is never recorded.
See [How to monitor transaction isolation level changes in SQL Profiler or in any other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539500/how-to-monitor-transaction-isolation-level-changes-in-sql-profiler-or-in-any-oth) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You picked the wrong tools because with Entity Framework Profiler you can easily check the isolation level (and lots of information about EF behaviour).

This is my transaction sample :

```
begin transaction with isolation level: ReadCommitted
```

[image: EF Profiler]

More info : https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof/learn

Comment: @Ilya; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.